# In Objective-C, the rule that designated initializer always get called is not always obeyed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, designated-initializer

Can we rely on the fact that in Objective-C, the rule is that a class's designated initializer is always called for sure?  Or can we say, it should be almost always true, except a couple of exceptions? For example, for `UIView`, the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIView) says:

> initWithFrame:
>
> If you create a view object programmatically, this method is the
> designated initializer for the UIView class. Subclasses can override
> this method to perform any custom initialization but must call super
> at the beginning of their implementation.
>
> If you use Interface Builder
> to design your interface, this method is not called when your view
> objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file. Objects in a nib
> file are reconstituted and then initialized using their initWithCoder:
> method

Or can we say that, if it is programmatically, the rule should always apply for well designed classes, but Interface Builder is a bit different because it sort of "revive" or build the object from a non-programmatic way.  If so, are they other exceptions in general when we do iOS programming?

Answer (score 4):

*The fact is that class designed with Interface Builder are unarchived and not initialized .*

Being archived involves that the class is not initialized but unarchived, so the `initWithCoder:` method takes responsibility for setting up the control when it's loaded using the archived attributes configured by Interface Builder.

You should put your initialization operations in the `awakeFromNib:` method that gets called in each case after the object is loaded, thus you will be sure that your initialization statements will be called .

Comment: `awakeFromNib:` doesn’t get called when you create the object programmatically. I’d recommend doing the initial setup in `layoutSubviews` (for `UIView` subclasses)